# How to check if a JSON object is empty

Tags: json, oracle

This is the JSON {"payload":{}}.

How do I check if the value object of payload key is an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle 12.2, you can use `JSON_EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN JSON_EXISTS( value, '$.payload' )
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS has_payload,
       CASE
       WHEN JSON_EXISTS( value, '$.payload.*' )
       THEN 'not empty'
       ELSE 'empty'
       END AS is_payload_empty
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB CHECK ( value IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( '{"payload":{}}' );
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | HAS_PAYLOAD | IS_PAYLOAD_EMPTY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | {"payload":{}} | true | empty |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=368e2bccb54875b8737344b35f27b522)*